# Iterate through checkboxes, send email and loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, loops, foreach

We're trying to send multiple emails at once to a list of companies, where an email can be checked or unchecked. If the email is checked, it needs to be sent to them. I've managed to get it to send the email to each email address ticked, but we want it to be one at a time. IE, rather than sending one email to Contact1, Contact2, Contact3 all in one go, we want to send one email to Contact1, loop through and then send the same email a second time to Contact2, and so forth.

Have tried a foreach loop, but it just sends the email three times to each recipient, rather than to one recipient at a time whilst only showing their email in the "To" field.

The code that sends the email is as follows:

```
        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "",
            Port = 25,
            EnableSsl = false,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
        };

        //Set message details, ensuring HTML is displayed when sent
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        })
            //Try send the email to the users
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(message); //Send the message to selected users

                Response.Redirect("~/BulkEmail/Index"); //Redirect back to the Index page if send is successful.
            }
            catch
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Home/Failure");
            }
```

This works fine, but as it'll be going to external emails we want them to each receive one at a time. The view in which emails are collected and "checked" is as follows:

```
@{
    string Email;
    Email = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1] + "@email.email";
}
@{
    int count = 1;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "BulkEmail", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<label>To:</label> @User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1]<br />
<label>From:</label> <input type="text" name="txtFrom" value="@Email" /><br />
<table border="1" width="100%">
<label>BCC:</label>@foreach (var item in Model)
                   {
    <tr width="100%">
        <td>
            @count
        </td>
        <td wdith="25">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td wdith="25">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tblContact.Company)
        </td>
        <td wdith="25">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td wdith="25" align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" value="@item.Email" checked="checked"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MailRecipientId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.MailRecipientId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.MailRecipientId })
        </td>
    </tr>     
                       count += 1;
                   }
    </table><br />
<label>Subject:</label> <input type="text" name="txtSubject" value="Quotations Needed"/>
<textarea name="message"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="BOOM THE EMAILS!" />
}
@Html.Action("TinyMCE", "Include")
```

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like it should be a foreach loop, but I'm not 100% sure on how to implement it correctly in this particular instance.

Thanks

**Requested Code:**

```
            var fromName = @User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
        var fromAddress = Request.Form["txtFrom"];
        var toAddress = Request.Form["chkBox"];
        var subject = Request.Form["txtSubject"];
        var q = Request.Unvalidated.Form;
        var messageBody = q["message"];
```

**Controller Update**

```
public ActionResult SendEmail()
    {

        //Create variables for where the message is going internally, setting the subject and body whilst allowing an unvalidated HTML tinyMCE box to be posted.
        var fromName = @User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
        var fromAddress = Request.Form["txtFrom"];
        var toAddress = Request.Form["chkBox[]"];
        var subject = Request.Form["txtSubject"];
        var q = Request.Unvalidated.Form;
        var messageBody = q["message"];

        String body = messageBody;

        MailMessage mail_client = new MailMessage();
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var email in toAddress)
        {
            mail_client.To.Add(chkBox[index]);
            index++;
        }
        mail_client.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
        mail_client.Subject = subject;
        mail_client.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail_client.Body = body;


        {
            //Create new SMTP client and give server details
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "",
                Port = 25,
                EnableSsl = false,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            };

            //Set message details, ensuring HTML can be displayed when sent
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body,
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            })
                //Try send the email to the users
                try
                {
                    smtp.Send(message); //Send the message to selected users

                    Response.Redirect("~/BulkEmail/Index"); //Redirect back to the Index page if send is successful.
                }
                //If the email doesn't send, allow the page to redirect rather than giving a vile error!
                catch
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Home/Failure");
                }

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: show the code where you check the checked list and add the address to To

Comment: @Sachu I've added the "toAddress" area of the code to the main post. It's then used in the second code block of the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of chkbox to "chkbox[]"
So in the controller you will get a parameter (string[] chkbox) which contain only checked ones..

then create a mail message object

```
MailMessage mail_client = new MailMessage();
 int index = 0
  foreach (string email in chkbox)
   {
   mail_client.To.Add(chkbox[index]);  
    index++;
   }

mail_client.From = new MailAddress("");
mail_client.Subject = subject;
mail_client.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail_client.Body = body;

smtp.Host = "";
smtp.Port = ;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Send(mail_client);
```

then you can use the same for sending mails

Answer (score 1):

Add all your email address that you want to send to an array such as:

```
//Email Address
List<string> recipients= new List<string>();
recipients.Add("Email1");
recipients.Add("Email2");
recipients.Add("Email3");
recipients.Add("Email4");
recipients.Add("Email5");
```

Then do a for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < recipients.Count; i++)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.To.Add(recipients[i]);
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.From = from;
    message.Body = body;
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = smtpClient;
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: The emails are read from a database, so adding each email into an array would mean they're hardcoded wouldn't they?

Comment: You can still add them to an array from the database with a select query. What kind of database?

Comment: Ok so how about adding an SQL datasource to the `.aspx` page with a `select distinct emailAddress from tablename`. Use that datasource to populate a hidden dropdown list and use that to populate the array. Trying to make it simple but there are 100 different ways you could do it

Comment: can you use SQL in a razorview page (forgot to mention that's what we're using, sorry). Been trying to find ways to use that as opposed to LINQ but not been able to find it!